# Get actual height of scaled transformed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform

Is it possible to get the actual `height` of a element that has been scaled with

```
transform: scale(...);
```

I have tried the following, but they are returning the original `height`

```
$('element').css('height');  // 16px (demo)

$('element').height(); // 21px (demo)
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvzXJ/**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a while, i have found the solution to this

You have to use

```
Element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Like so

```
$('element')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to Get actual height of scaled transformed element. [`jsFiddle`]

user 'outerHeight' instead of 'height'

http://jsfiddle.net/ZvzXJ/8/

```
//full code here

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
.button{
    -webkit-transform: scale( 3 );
    margin:100px;
    display:block;
}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
         alert($('.button').outerHeight()+ 'px');
         alert($('.button').css('height'));
    });   
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button class="button">Welcome</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why you got 4 votes for that? it doesn't work at all.

Comment: check this js fiddle code and working for me.

Comment: Yes, i have tried all of the height methods in jQuery none of them work, so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: It's not working for you.

Comment: i check in window os and my browser is chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m .

Comment: this code working for me ( alert two time '22px').

Comment: Is the element `22px` in `height` though?

Comment: Change the `scale( 10 );` and it will still be `22px`